# Numeric prefixes for statamic fields

Tags: graphql, statamic

I'm really sorry if this is a dumb question. And please mark my question as a duplicate if needed...I just didn't find an appropriate answer.

My problem can be found in the picture below.

[image]

And my question is...why does statamic prefix some fields with numbers allthough it is not possible to query them with grahql? And if it is possible to query them...how?

Thanks in advance and I'm really sorry again if it is a dumb question.

Comment: Are you able to share your blueprint?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in joining the Statamic Discord server where there's always community members online ready to help. Not everyone's active on StackOverflow 